# Android back camera access Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-camera

Is there any new way to access the back camera in Android Chrome browser? It seems that the other solutions available on StackOverflow don't work. Is there a more up-to-date solution?

Comment: Did you try to research little more o internet. Did you work on native android app or just web JS/htm on mobile browser?  Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices to list all devices in js,